# How to prove that $f (x) = \mu (x + B)$ is measurable?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

If $S$ is a measurable Abelian group, and $\mu$ probability measure on $S$,
how would you prove that
$$ f(x) = \mu (x + B) $$
is measurable function for every fixed measurable set $B$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $\mu(x+B)=\int_S 1_{B}(y-x)\ \mu(dy)$.

By general measure theory, the map  $x\mapsto\int_S f(x,y)\ \mu(dy)$ is measurable for any jointly measurable, bounded  $f:S\times S\to \mathbb{R}$.

This result can be found, for instance, in Lemma 1.26 (p. 14) of Kallenberg's *Foundations of Modern Probability (2nd edition)*. The proof uses a monotone class argument.

Comment: If you have a different measure theory text, you will probably find this fact as part of the proof of Fubini's theorem.