# Measuring closed balls

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, banach-spaces

Let $(X,\parallel \cdot \parallel)$ be Banach and 
$$\mathcal{BC}(X)=\{A\subset X\colon A \text{ is closed, bounded and non-empty}\}.$$ The natural metric on this space is the Hausdorff distance $d_H$ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance)

Let $C_x(r)$ be the closed ball around $x\in X$ with radius $r$. How can I show that the map $f\colon X\to\mathcal{BC}(X)$ where $f(x)=C_x(r)$ is continuous w.r.t. $d_H$?

And is the map $g\colon X\to\mathbf{R}$ with $g(x)=\mu(C_x(R))$ Borel measurable for a Borel measure $\mu$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_1,x_2\in X$ and $r_1,r_2>0$ with $\|x_1-x_2\|\leq \varepsilon/2$
 and $|r_1-r_2|\leq \varepsilon/2$. We will bound the distance between the
 two closed balls $C_1:=C_{x_1}(r_1)$ and $C_2:=C_{x_2}(r_2)$.

Let $w\in C_1$. If $w\in C_2$, then $\inf_{z\in B_2} \|w-z\|=0$.
Let's assume
that $w\notin C_2$, that is, $\|w-x_2\| > r_2$. Then we have 
$$r_2\leq \|w-x_2\|\leq \|w-x_1\|+\|x_1-x_2\|\leq r_1+\varepsilon/2
\leq r_2+\varepsilon.$$

Letting $w^*=x_2+{r_2\over \|w-x_2\|} (w-x_2)$ we have $w^*\in B_2$
 and $\|w-w^*\|\leq \|w-x_2\|-r_2\leq \varepsilon.$ 
so $\inf_{z\in B_2} \|w-z\|\leq \varepsilon.$

Combining the two cases, and taking the supremum over $w\in C_1$, we deduce that 
$\sup_{w\in C_1}\inf_{z\in C_2} \|w-z\|\leq \varepsilon$. 
By symmetry we get $d_H(C_1,C_2)\leq \varepsilon$.

From this you can show that  $(x,r)\mapsto B_x(r)$ is jointly continuous 
from  $X\times (0,\infty)$ to $\mathcal{BC}(X)$. This is a bit stronger
than the result you wanted.

---

Since $C_x(R)=x+C_0(R)$, your second question is answered here:
[How to prove that $f (x) = \mu (x + B)$ is measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30661/how-to-prove-that-f-x-mu-x-b-is-measurable/30664#30664) assuming that $\mu$ is a non-negative, finite measure.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that the question is now [on MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92706/) (posted by the same person or from the same computer)

Comment: Thanks. Maybe the OP will get a better answer there. Mine is the first thing that popped into my head.

Comment: As noted on MO, this turned out to be from a homework assignment